# Get first 3 words from non English string in php

Tags: php

I want first 3 words from a non-english string in php. For example:

```
এখানে কিংকর্তব্যবিমূঢ় হবার কোনো সুযোগ নেই
```

I have found it is possible for English text as:

```
$phrase = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit';
echo implode(' ', array_slice(str_word_count($phrase, 2), 0, 3));
```

But it does not work for my non-english(bengali) text. Could someone tell me how can I do it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"does not work"* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `explode`  and `implode`

1) `explode` the string by space

2) get the first three slice using `array_slice`

3) again `implode` it with space

```
<?php

  $string = 'এখানে কিংকর্তব্যবিমূঢ় হবার কোনো সুযোগ নেই';
  $array = array_slice(explode(" ",$string),0,3);

  echo implode(" ",$array)."<br>";

  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode`, `array_slice` and `implode` for this:

```
$string = "এখানে কিংকর্তব্যবিমূঢ় হবার কোনো সুযোগ নেই";
$parts = explode(" ", $string);
$x = array_slice($parts, 0, 3);
print implode(" ", $x);
# এখানে কিংকর্তব্যবিমূঢ় হবার
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not mention what version of PHP you are using but the main pain with PHP and UTF is that it does not sometimes work together as many string manipulation methods are/were mostly based on assumption "1 char = 1 byte". MBString extension addresses this in many cases yet not everywhere. In your case `str_word_count()` needs to be replaced with multibyte aware counterpart, i.e. `mb_split()`:

```
echo implode(' ', array_slice(mb_split("\s", $phrase), 0, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here as well, you could use the power of regular expressions:

```
^(?:\b\p{Bengali}+\s*){3}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/CJ3Cxo/1).

---

Which in `PHP` would be:

```
<?php
$string = "এখানে কিংকর্তব্যবিমূঢ় হবার কোনো সুযোগ নেই";
$regex = '~^(?:\b\p{Bengali}+\s*){3}~u';
if (preg_match($regex, $string, $match)) {
    echo $match[0];
}

# এখানে কিংকর্তব্যবিমূঢ় হবার 
?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/mGMVPa).

Comment: thanks to your help me. I have already done it by previous answer.

Comment: @StreetCoder: That's ok, but does this one work as well for you?